# How to create a dataframe from a dictionary that have a dictionary within

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that contains the following dictionary:

```
{0: nan,1: nan,2: "{'ga:productSku': 148223, 'ga:dimension16': '4511', 'ga:productName': 'Amargo Terma Serrano 1.35 L','ga:productCategoryHierarchy': '/Almacén/Bebidas/Aguas/Gaseosas/Jugos/A Base de Hierbas'}",3: "{'ga:productSku': 248146, 'ga:dimension16': '1001', 'ga:productName': 'Aperitivo Cynar 900 Ml', 'ga:productCategoryHierarchy': '/Almacén/Bebidas/Aguas/Gaseosas/Jugos/Aperitivos'}"}
```

How can I put the keys that start with 'ga:' as a column?

Comment: Please see [ask], which specifically says not to use screenshots of code/data/errors.

Comment: Copy code in question instead of image